# How to sort the elements of a list based off associated index python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am looking to sort MyArray[] of size n elements so that MyArray[n] = n. If the element is missing it should be replaced with a -1. Here is an example:
Input : MyArray = [-1, -1, 6, 1, 9, 3, 2, -1, 4, -1]
Output : [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 6, -1, -1, 9]

```
MyArray = [-1, -1, 6, 1, 9, 3, 2, -1, 4, -1]
MyArrayNew = []
for n in MyArray:
    if n <= len(MyArray):
         MyArrayNew[n] = n
    else:
         MyArrayNew[n] = -1
print(MyArrayNew)
```

Here is my code thus far, any pointers on how to properly code this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making two mistakes.

1. You use `n` as an index as well as the value. From the for loop it can be seen that n is the value of each element in the list `MyArray`. But later on you use this as an index when you call `MyArrayNew[n]`. When `n` is -1 there is propably some things that happen that you do not want.
2. lists indices can only be changed if they already exist. `MyArrayNew` starts of empty, so you can't say: change the third index to three, because the third index doesn't exist yet.

There are many approaches to solve this problem. I'll give one:

To solve the second problem I suggest appending instead of assigning indices. To solve the first problem, you could use `for i in range len(arr):`, but I prefer enumerate.

I'll also approach it the other way around: cycle through the indices and check if it should be its index value, or -1.

This results in the following code:

```
MyArray = [-1, -1, 6, 1, 9, 3, 2, -1, 4, -1]
MyArrayNew = []
for index, value in enumerate(MyArray):
    if index in MyArray:
        MyArrayNew.append(index)
    else:
        MyArrayNew.append(-1)

print(MyArrayNew)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to sort an array that I know in python

1. for an **inplace** sorting: apply the `sort()` method to your array as
   `MyArray.sort()`
2. The second way is to use nested FOR ... LOOP and compare values in the array from Index 0 to the final item. I normally use a temp value to keep the previous value, compare it with the current, and swap the values according to the size. The example code below

```
     for i in range(len(MyArray)):
            #outer loop
            for j in range(i+1, len(MyArray)):
                #start from i+1,  why because you always want to compare the 
                     previous element with the current element in the outer loop
                if(MyArray[i] > MyArray[j]):
                    temp = MyArray[i]
                    MyArray[i] = MyArray[j]
                    MyArray[j] = temp
         print(MyArray)
```